# Boolean endpoint within a RESTful API

Tags: design, rest, api-design

I am currently designing a JSON RESTful API which should have a boolean endpoint such as `/item/vote` which can either be `false` meaning that a user has not voted for a specific item or `true` meaning that he has voted.

I am currently struggling to select one out of multiple possible designs:

**HTTP status codes**

```
PUT /item/vote => set to true
DELETE /item/vote => set to false
GET /item/vote => status code 204 => true | status code 404 => false
```

**JSON**

```
PUT /item/vote HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "vote": true
}
```

```
GET /item/vote HTTP/1.1


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "vote": true
}
```

Is any of these two approaches better or is it just a matter of preference? I am currently preferring the HTTP status code approach because I have already seen it.

Comment: How do you distinguish a real 404 from a successful no vote?

Comment: There is such thing. You can just vote. Similar to the (old) way of liking on Facebook.

Comment: What is your mechanism by which you know that a GET request to a resource actually completed? How do you distinguish this case from a the very real case where the endpoint could simply be Not Found.

Comment: In any case the resource should be named like a thing (`voteStatus`) and not like a verb `vote`.

Comment: `vote` can be a noun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second approach is highly preferable. `PUT` is intended to replace the resource on the server with the content you're `PUT`ting. Likewise, `DELETE` is intended to delete a resource, not to set its value.